Attic storage help
Just bought this home and finally moved all objects from A to B and need more storage. I know, who would have thunk it?
https://imgur.com/a/c4nJDnF
In short, 2x6 16oc and would like to put 23/32 OSB up there for storage and to be able to have a stable platform for possible maintenance needs. Not planning on covering end to end, just build out from the pull down ladder.
Was planning on using 2x3 over the joists as a platform for the OSB.
Trying to decide between laying them on top a la this video.
https://youtu.be/gNUPmhF9l2A?si=9sj4gJ4b4XrW9iJI
Or to run them perpendicular to the joists like this video
https://youtu.be/6HuCQaytV7E?si=XSmtMHW0goFkFH4T
I have read enough to worry about the added weight but is this a major concern or should I be fine as it is not going to be used as a living space.
Please help a new home owner out
Thank you

You may want to consider if 6 inches of insulation is enough before you cover it with  flooring.

In short, you haven't mentioned span, and 2x6 are not much of a floor joist anyway. Consult an engineer...date of construction (which code applied when it was built) may inform whether it is likely to have been built for a 20 PSF "storage" load (in areas more than 42" high, accesseed from a pull down ladder) or if it was built "however it was built" with no specfic code being designed for. If date and applicable code indicate the 20 PSF loading, you might be able to skip the engineer if you respect that.

Barring advice of an engineer, rather than 23/32 OSB (24" floor span) you want the  lightest product you can find with 16" floor rating, since you have 16" studs. Thick OSB is heavy (so it cuts into your storage capacity)
